# Resize form to fit its caption

Tags: delphi, c++builder

How can I determine the required width of a Delphi/C++ Builder form so its caption fits? I'm using C++ Builder Pro 10.4.1. Note I am using VCL styles (skin) so not sure if a generic Windows solution will work (not that I could find one). Thanks!

Comment: The approximate way is the window width minus `GetSystemMetrics( SM_CXSIZE )` as per buttons minus `GetSystemMetrics( SM_CXSMICON )`. This implies knowing/being flexible about which window you have (normal/tool), which buttons, an icon...

Comment: @AmigoJack: I didn't interpret the Q like that. I think the OP wants to find the width of the title bar *text*.

Comment: Get the width of the caption text in the font used for the caption, add some width for the corner icons as needed, and then use [`AdjustWindowRect()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-adjustwindowrect) to get the total window size adjusted for borders and such.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau won't icon and form buttons width change with style and DPI settings?

Comment: @MikeVersteeg check if you can query the OS for those sizes using `GetSystemMetrics()` or equivilent